# rails application elastic beanstalk timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just uploaded my rails 3.1 app , to elastic beanstalk. And while the database and everything seems setup right . Attempting to open my app up , just causes a browser timeout . the
only error i can see in the logs is 
:2013/07/10 14:19:33 [error] 1741#0: *4 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is not
found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD /
HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"

i have used a static pages controller and have my pages in the view , i don not know what i should be doing to configure passenger , or whether there is something else wrong with the way i have deployed my app . The rest of the logs are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p43s6ttx5amld5b/https___elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-354318918039.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com_resources%252Fenvironments%252Flogs%252Ftail%252Fe-rsmkbmnmgc%252Fi-13b88c44%252FTailLogs-1373467754283.pdf)

thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, I know it has been a while but I was struggling with the same issue and finally got it fixed. Did you try opening up any other pages on your app?

Comment: @SamanthaCabral . I tried opening other pages but nothing did open. Had to move back to heroku. I really want to know how you fixedit though as it might help in the future . I later thought i might have had the error because i renamed my project externally but did not edit the rails files that contained project name

Comment: I had a few issues: trying opening other pages showed that I was having issues with twitter bootstrap - so I debugged that for a while . But the crux of the issue was HOW i removed public/index.html - git rm public/index.html caused the issue. I ended up doing just rm public/index.html, then git add --all, followed by git commit and push. That worked for me.

Comment: @SamanthaCabral now that i think about it that could be the issue . thanks that will help in the future

Answer (score 0):

Your db migration failed to run:

```
[root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: 
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh
2013-07-10 14:25:20,500 [INFO] (1759 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] 
[root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: Rake task failed to run, 
skipping database migrations.
```

The easiest way to figure this out, is to deploy again, `ssh` to the server and manually run the command to see why it failed.  This could be because of a number of reasons, including e.g. by default rejecting git repositories in your gemfile (`bundle install` I recall will run but `db:migrate` will fail).  There are ways around all of this, we just need more information to help.